# Guid/Uuid in PHP with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to store uuids in the database as BINARY(16) but I need to accept them and present them as the XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX format. Before I jump to split the guid in PHP code (what a fun that is!), are there any libraries or functions that do this out-of-the-box?

Comment: [this link is nice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950202/how-to-store-uuid-as-number)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first remove the dashes with [Replace()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)
and then use [Unhex()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex)

> Performs the inverse operation of HEX(str). That is, it interprets each pair of hexadecimal digits in the argument as a number and converts it to the character represented by the number.

Comment: +1 There may be a library, but this is a short task for just converting them. Unless you're generating them, I'd just spend the few extra lines to code your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean BINARY(36) instead of BINARY(16)

Try http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid

CakePHP has some neat functionality for uuids and it works automatically for CHAR(36) and BINARY(36) from what I understand. Either way you could dig into the source a bit to see if it has what you need.

Edit: Here is a stand alone class that can generate and convert into just about any format you might need: http://www.shapeshifter.se/2008/09/29/uuid-generator-for-php/ I posted this in the below comment but wanted to make sure the link is easily visible for other users.

Comment: No, I mean BINARY(16). I want to store the underlying value, not the expanded character representation.

Comment: OK I see. The PECL library should do it for you but this might be better: http://www.shapeshifter.se/2008/09/29/uuid-generator-for-php/
It not only generates UUIDs but can also convert to different formats including BINARY(16)