# MySQL: Retrieving all fields SELECT * when one of the fields is binary and needs to HEX

Tags: mysql, database

I have a primary kew which is a *binary(16)* UUID in a field called binid.
I would like to get **ALL** columns including the binary id with a SELECT statement.

I know I can do "SELECT * FROM TABLE", but how to combine with HEX(binid)?

This works when I get individual fields: "SELECT HEX(binid) AS binid FROM TABLE"
but I dont want to mention all of the fields (too many). Is there a way to get ALL and HEX in one statement?

PS. I am creating based on stackoverflow question: [How to store uuid as number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950202/how-to-store-uuid-as-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting `*` will select all the fields as they are, without transformations. To select them changing their formats you will have to specify all the fields you want to select spearated by `,`.

For instance:

```
SELECT HEX(`binid`) as `bindid`, `name`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`birthday`) as `birthday`, `gender` FROM `table`;
```

You can apply as many transformations you want.

You can also do this:

```
SELECT HEX(`binid`) as `hexdid`, * FROM `table`;
```

In this case the result will have both the `binid` in hex format, named `hexid`, and also the original `binid` aswell with the other fields of the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2, col3 from table
```

e.g. if table is called T and set as thus:

```
        T
=================
| binid | A | B |
| 0     | 1 | a |
| 1     | 2 | b |
| 10    | 3 | c |

select hex(binid), A, B from table
```

Comment: I get that BUT is there a way without listing each column? I have hundreds of columns in this table.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

`Select *, HEX(binid) as clearBinId from Table`

This will select all the columns (including binid) and also select the HEX(binid) as a column called 'clearBinId'