# type for an ID in my mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have created a blog in php where users can post comments.I have created a table in mysql that holds users comments. My table holds for each comment its' Id number. I may have billions or trillions of comments. What is the best **type** to use for my comment_id? I use int(11) but I think that this will be not enough for later... any better idea what type to use?

Comment: `int(11)` is still just a standard 4 byte `int` (See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5634147/2594742)

Answer (score 4):

I like using UUIDs to identify rows because they:

1. Are large: 128 bits
2. Allow for better replication due to not being tied to a sequence/identity generator
3. Are globally-unique as opposed to unique only within that sequence

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122934/best-way-to-handle-large-uuid-as-a-mysql-table-primary-key) for how to use UUIDs in MySQL.

Using UUIDs will be slightly slower than `int`s because the amount of data is larger, but in my experience the flexibility that UUIDs provide outweighs any performance penalty.

Comment: so it will be better to change int(11) to BINARY(16)?

Comment: "Better" is really subjective, but in my experience, UUIDs are the way to go for row IDs for anything non-trivial. I certainly think it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `MyISAM` storage engine you can create an auto incrementing composite key.
Doing it this way you then effectively have a separate sequence for each blog post, making it less likely you'll max out the int data type.

**Table Create:**

```
CREATE TABLE Comments (
  `blog_post_id` int not null,
  `comment_id` int not null auto_increment,
  `text` text,
  primary key(`blog_post_id`,`comment_id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

**Insert (just like normal):**

```
INSERT INTO Comments (`blog_post_id`,`text`) VALUES
(1,'First!!!'),
(2,'Some sensible comment'),
(1,'OMG... Posting First!! is dumb.'),
(1,'^ I second this...'),
(2,'TURTLES!!'),
(1,'...');
```

**Data:**

```
BLOG_POST_ID    COMMENT_ID    TEXT
1               1             First!!!
1               2             OMG... Posting First!! is dumb.
1               3             ^ I second this...
1               4             ...
2               1             Some sensible comment
2               2             TURTLES!!
```

See this: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8befe9/2/0)

Comment: You could also go a step further with this and make `comment_id` an `int unsigned` which would allow you up to `4,294,967,295` comment per blog post. Or if you're really paranoid about hitting that limit... `bigint unsigned` goes up to `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`.

Answer (score 0):

your table `blog`

```
blog_id | blog_title | blog | published_date | blabla
```

Now, here comes a `blog_comment` table

```
comment_id | blog_id | comment
```

Now, i guess you won't have to worry about things