# Creating a UUID field in PhpMyadmin MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a UUID within PHPMyAdmin on my web host/server, I've created a table called 'video' and I've inserted a field in there called 'uuid', but I don't know how to actually turn the field into a UUID, I have a feeling I'm missing something really basic here, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a column of an appropriate data type to store it, then when inserting data use the [UUID() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). There are several means to store the resulting data, including in a CHAR type, but since it's a number you may wish to store it as a number. [This is a pretty good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950202/how-to-store-uuid-as-number). Also, [this thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,49626,49626) has additional information that may help.

When inserting from phpMyAdmin, look for the Function dropdown, which has "UUID()" near the bottom.

Comment: I've changed it to INT to represent it as a number and given it a count 36 as that's how much UUID's are correct? Strangely, I don't have a UUID option in the whole of my drop down, here is a picture of what I am seeing http://imgur.com/4BQomeY

Comment: Keep scrolling the function list down, it should be near the very bottom.

Comment: This is odd, I've double checked and there definitely isn't a UUID option, is it specific to a certain field type? I tried changing the field type to CHAR, VARCHAR etc. also but it gave me the same options as the ones in the screenshot, that screenshot I showed you was at the bottom of the list. I'm using PHPMyAdmin Version 2.11.4 if that helps?

Comment: I've done a quick test by downloading the 2.11.12 release and also don't see the UUID function. I'd suggest updating your phpMyAdmin version, that should resolve the problem.

Comment: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#upgrading-from-an-older-version may help with that.

Comment: Cheers Isaac I am currently using a free hosting server, so there may be limitations to upgrading PHPMyAdmin, will this update method work for that?

Comment: If your host provides the phpMyAdmin, you could bug them to update it :-) But yes, you can install your own phpMyAdmin independent of theirs, although you should give the folder a different name than what they use to avoid conflict. Follow the instructions for a new installation instead of an upgrade in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if like me, you were looking for how to create the UUID field on phpmyadmin, especially the type you have to choose, here is a screenshot after it was automatically done by laravel (It is the "id" named field of course in this example): [UUID field type in phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wDGi.png)