# UUID without slashes + Hibernate + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, uuid

I save UUID without slashes as varbinary(16) in MySql. I will like to use annotation to map this field in Hibernate. Am I able to do it? Please help.

Here is my mapping:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", unique = true) 
private String productId;
```

Here is my insert:

```
INSERT INTO `item`
(`ID`,
`TITLE`)
VALUES
(
UNHEX('f4e01440cfd011e39c1a0800200c9a66'),
'Apple' 
);
```

But id become something like ��%14@��%11��%1A%08%00 %0C�f in my code.

Comment: I am writing my code based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950202/how-to-store-uuid-as-number

Comment: I think this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532492/hibernate-uuid-generation-and-mysql-uuid-function-uuid/23532603?noredirect=1#23532603