# JPA changes UUID value

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, uuid

I use varbinary(36) to save UUID in MySql as primary keys. And I use EclipseLink to auto gen my data objects. It gens primary key as String. I inserted data as below. When I use JPA to select * from country, the COUNTRY_ID becames: '66653565373765302D663832312D313165332D613361632D303830303230306339613636'. What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO `didicity`.`country`
(`COUNTRY_ID`, `NAME`, `SHORT_NAME`)
VALUES
('fe5e77e0-f821-11e3-a3ac-0800200c9a66', 
'United State',
'USA'
);



@Id
@Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
private String countryId;
```

Comment: The value that has been returned appears to be the hexadecimal equivalent of the value that you inserted. That's not completely surprising given that it's a var __binary__ column.

Comment: What should I do to make them in sync? convert them? I need to run select where from db by using that key.

Comment: Perhaps the answer here [How to store uuid as number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950202/how-to-store-uuid-as-number) will help you out?

Comment: Thx Steve C! If i need to save UUID as varbinary(36) in MySQL, is there anything in Java code I can do to make it work?